# Как сгенерировать xml в javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна функция обратная `$.parseXML` - её я `XML` считываю.

Теперь нужно запись новую структуру, чтобы передать в этот вызов:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(Xml_2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

последовательный вызов:
childNodes
createElement
textContent или setAttribute
appendChild